# SSIS script task error message

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ssis

I received the following error message when running `SSIS` package. The Script Task is using `Microsoft Visual C# 2008`. Can you please help me to fix the problem?

Thank you very much! I also attach error message:

```
Error: 2015-12-22 02:58:08.28
   Code: 0x00000001
   Source: Script Task 
   Description: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a notification from a service application.
   at System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.ShowCore(IWin32Window owner, String text, String caption, MessageBoxButtons buttons, MessageBoxIcon icon, MessageBoxDefaultButton defaultButton, MessageBoxOptions options, Boolean showHelp)
   at System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(String text)
   at ST_d27b216cd7d64713b54c81f6ac28d805.csproj.ScriptMain.Main()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   at System.Type.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()
End Error
DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).
```

C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ST_d27b216cd7d64713b54c81f6ac28d805.csproj
{
    [System.AddIn.AddIn("ScriptMain", Version = "1.0", Publisher = "", Description = "")]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {

        #region VSTA generated code
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion

        public void Main()
        {
            // TODO: Add your code here
            System.IO.FileInfo fi;
            String FilePath = null;

            DateTime ModifiedTime = (DateTime)Dts.Variables["File_Modified"].Value;


            DateTime LoadDate = (DateTime)Dts.Variables["File_Last_Load_Date"].Value;

            Dts.Variables["isModified"].Value = false;


            FilePath = Dts.Variables["SourceFolder"].Value.ToString();
            ModifiedTime = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(FilePath);

            Dts.Variables["File_Modified"].Value = ModifiedTime; 
            // fi.LastWriteTime;
            int result = DateTime.Compare(ModifiedTime, LoadDate);

            if (result > 0)
            {
                  MessageBox.Show("File Modified after last load in staging");
                Dts.Variables["isModified"].Value = true;
            }
            else
            {
               MessageBox.Show("file is not modified since last load");
                Dts.Variables["isModified"].Value = false;
            }

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message extracted from your stack trace is:

> Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a notification from a service application.

You have to remember that although when you are debugging your SSIS package you have a nice UI (BIDS or SQL Server Tools shells depending on your environment) but really it is not designed to be have a UI. What would you expect to happen when this package is deployed to a server and called by a SQL Job? i.e. Where would the message box show? Who would click "OK" to allow the thread to resume?

You probably want to just [fire an information event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136054.aspx) if you are looking to post feedback, something like:

```
bool fireAgain = false;
Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "Script Task", "File Modified after last load in staging", String.Empty, 0, ref fireAgain);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, GarethD! I will remove the two lines of messageBox.Show() since the code is called a SQL job. I think it will be enough to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error is raised because your script task is trying to display a message box and showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Therefore if you want to output a message, you could use `Dts.Log` instead, see the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136131.aspx) documentation for further details.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, Jaco! I will remove the two lines of messageBox.Show() since the code is called a SQL job. I think it will be enough to solve the problem.